# What does the "Share it with the same people" option do when making a copy?

Tags: google-docs, google-drive-sharing

When making a copy of a document in Google Docs from **File** > **Make a copy…**, there is an option to **Share it with the same people**.  What does that option do?  Does it share the doc with the same people as the source folder or the destination folder?  If the destination folder is already shared with a number of people, does it override those permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Selecting this option:

[image: 0]

---

### means that everyone listed here:

[image: 0]

---

### will be able to find this document copy on their Drive under:

[image]

Comment: Are those the sharing settings of the document itself, the folder it was copied from, or the folder it's being copied to?

Comment: @Vincent sharing settings of the document itself - if we talking only in terms of "Share it with the same people" checkbox