# How to (easily) clear a Google Doc's edit history?

Tags: google-docs

How do I clear (or hide) a shared Google Document's edit history? I want to share a document with others but don't want the edit history visible to others.

The only way I've found is to make a copy of the document and share the new document. But this only works if I haven't already shared the document with others; this workaround wouldn't work for an already-shared document.

Comment: thats why you have **Share it with the same people** checkbox - https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/131165/186471

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the best course of action is to make a copy as you mentioned it in your question and in process of making a copy tick the **Share it with the same people** checkbox. Not ideal workaround but atm the only one.

<sub>**https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/131165/186471**</sub>

Comment: That's too bad. It seems bizarre to me that Google wouldn't allow the author of a document to hide the revisions that went into it. They are treating someone's shared document like a public Wikipedia entry (exposing all the edits).

Comment: @DimitriS. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score -1):

*From a Google Expert Volunteer:*

If you have only given the person "Commenting" permission (which allows them to comment and suggest edits), they won't have access to your version history. Only collaborators with "Editing" access can see the document's history.

Hope this helps.